# Open a "Thank You" -html page on submit (with php form mail)

Tags: php

I just installed a feedback form that uses php, but I'm very new to the language.

The form itself is working. My question is this:

At the moment the form echoes a "Thank You" string when it's submitted. Can I have it redirect the user to a html-page instead?

Here's is my php code:

```
    <?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: Myname'; 
    $to = 'info@mydomain.com'; 
    $subject = 'mydomain.com feedback';
    $human = $_POST['human'];
    $answers = array('red','Red');  

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if ($_POST['submit'] && in_array($human,$answers)) {                 
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Thanks!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong!</p>'; 
    } 
    } else if ($_POST['submit'] && !in_array($human,$answers)) {
    echo '<p>You ansered the captcha wrong!</p>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: If you only need to redirect to another page, you could use the [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function. :)

Comment: see my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of echoing `'<p>Thanks!</p>';`

Just change it to a `header()` function...

And direct to whatever URL you wanna go to...

Example....

```
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
   header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
} else {
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can using header location.
Take a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php